# Show latest tweet's location, then tweet on a web page

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, geolocation

I would like to be able to display on a web page that a twitter user was "last seen" in X location, "where he said" whatever their latest tweet is. This is for a user that has geolocation enabled, and I am doing this to track them on a trip. What is the easiest way to do this? It would look like this:

[user] was last seen in [latest tweet location (city/state, not geopoints)] where he said: [latest tweet]

Any help/advice is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have tried this adding this to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywebsite.com/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterLocation&count=1"></script>
```

And then modifying twitter's blogger.js to add this at the top:

```
function twitterLocation(twitters) {
  var statusHTML = [];
  for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
    var place= twitters[i].place.full_name;
    statusHTML.push('+place+');
  }
  document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = statusHTML.join('');
}
```

and finally, putting a

```
<span id="location></span>
```

and

```
<div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
```

in the html as well.

The tweet comes out okay, but the only thing placed in the "location" span is just the text, "+place"

Is it possible that I'm on any sort of right track here?

Answer (score 1):

You should Google for the answer here, but I would simply use the REST API: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

The last location would be in the "geo" parameter.

Then use the Google Reverse Geocoding API to pull out a location string:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Thank you for the response! How do I grab the "<full_name>" data from that XML and display it in html?

Comment: Name = "user": {"name"}

In the XML response I suppose it would be: <user><name>Full Name Here</name></user>

Comment: Oh no I'm sorry, I mean that if I use XML format, there are tags that will give me the place name, and within the <place> tag, there is a tag called <full_name> which holds the full name of the place - so that's the data I want, but I am just not really experienced enough to know how to pull that data from that file and display it on the page.